# Off hover function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm trying to do something on hover and off hover of `.mail img`. The on hover event is happening and the code in it is being executed, but the off hover event is not.

To simplify it, I replaced my code with alerts and the off hover alert isn't firing either.

```
$('.mail img').hover(function(){
    alert('on hover');
},
function(){
    alert('off hover');
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is because you are using `alert` to test with. The event used for the hover out is `mouseleave`. This does not fire when the `alert` from `mouseenter` is shown.

Change the code to use `console.log` (as you should when debugging) and it will work:

```
$('.mail img').hover(function(){
    console.log('on hover');
}, function(){
    console.log('off hover');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/skqretxp/)

Comment: I know it is bad practice to use alert. I'm only use them about 10% of the time still. But the off hover event still does not fire with console.log()s. My code doesn't actually have the alters.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? You can see from the fiddle that the code alone you have provided should be working fine.

Comment: Have no idea why off hover nor mouseleave nor mouseout is firing. No errors. Code is all valid. Thanks for the education, didn't know alert would mess with hover events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseout()` to check for the cursor leaving the elemnt

```
$('.mail img').mouseout(function(){
    alert('off hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('.mail img').mouseover(function(){
    alert('on hover');

}).mouseout(function(){
    alert('off hover');

});
```